# How to discriminate Weatherdata latitude and longitude from a more detailed list

Tags: list-manipulation

From [this](http://weather.gladstonefamily.net/cgi-bin/location.pl/pjsg_all_location.csv?csv=1) list of weather data how can I discriminate only latitude longitude for each station?

For example from the following sample I would need only the coordinates:

- "50136","","Aoluguya|Mohe, 15","","CN",**52.13333,122.51667**,433
- "50246","","Tahe|Ta-He, 23","","CN",**52.33330,124.80000**,465
- "50349","","Jinsong|Jiu-Hai-Lai, 15","","CN",**51.13330,124.05000**,610

Comment: Like in `SortBy[]`?

Comment: problem is how to discriminate stations lat lon ?? Some stations.... Example:Russian stations .. I think import[txt] .

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like playing with `Part`? `Cases` or something?

Comment: importing some data txt file then cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach based on the construction of your list:

```
rawdata = 
  Import["http://weather.gladstonefamily.net/cgi-bin/location.pl/pjsg_all_location.csv?csv=1"];
```

If you check how your list is constructed you have:

```
Tally[Map[Head, rawdata, {2}]]// Column
```

> ```
> {{{{Integer, String, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 14471}},
>  {{{String, String, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 33197}},
>  {{{Integer, String, String, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 42}},
>  {{{Real, String, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 2}},
>  {{{String, Integer, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 4720}},
>  {{{String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 1}},
>  {{{String, String, String, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 14}},
>  {{{String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 4}},
>  {{{String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Real, Real, Integer}, 1}}}
> ```

You can see if you wish keep only the `Real`s you are interested in (a.k.a. the coordinates) you need to delete the first column in order to keep *only* the coordinates:

```
Cases[#, _Real] & /@ rawdata[[All, 2 ;;]]
```

> ```
> {{65.98222, -161.15194}, {35.35052, -116.88837}, {37.24776, -112.82244}, <<52446>>, 
>  {41.78283, 123.49491}, {46.3326, 16.6093}, {40.33093, -3.74632}}
> ```

Note that it's very specific to your case and the way your list is constructed but the same approach can be used with different lists.